# ¿Cómo hacer un .map dentro de otro .map en React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, reactjs, typescript

Buenas,

Teniendo en el array1 objetos con campos id, numero y array2, quiero mostrar en una lista multiple el campo número, y dentro otra lista con los objetos del array2. 
Mi idea es mapear el primer array, pintar lo correspondiendo y dentro de ese mapeo mapear el array2.

En líneas de código he hecho esto:

```
render(){
    return(
        ayrray1.map((opcion) => (
            (<option key={opcion.id} value={opcion.id}>{opcion.numero}</option>)
            (opcion.array2.map((elem) =>
                (<option key={elem.id} value={elem.id}>{elem.numero}</option>)
                )
            )
        ))
}
```

No es capaz de pintarme las dos cosas. Por separado si, es decir cualquiera de los mapeos por separado lo hace correctamente, pero las dos juntas no. He probado a separar los elementos por ',' pero solamente se queda con el último.
¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente fuera del return mapea tus arrays y guárdalos en una variable. Luego, simplemente devuélvela.

```
let options = [];

ayrray1.map((opcion) => {
  options.push(
    <option key={opcion.id} value={opcion.id}>{opcion.numero}</option>
  );
  opcion.array2.map((elem) => (
    options.push(
      <option key={elem.id} value={elem.id}>{elem.numero}</option>
    )
  ))
});

return options;
```

**Ejemplo**

```
class Filters extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({
      options: [
        {
          id: 1,
          numero: 25,
          suboptions: [
            {
              id: 2,
              numero: 26
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  render () {
    let options = [];
    this.state.options.forEach((option) => {
      options.push(
        <option 
          key={option.id} 
          value={option.id}
        >
          {option.numero}
        </option>
      );
      option.suboptions.forEach((suboption) => {
        options.push(
          <option 
            key={suboption.id} 
            value={suboption.id}
          >
            {suboption.numero}
          </option>
        )
      })
    });

    return (
      <select>{ options }</select>
    )
  }
}
```